# vscode debug c file failed showing no such file

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb

I writed a single c file and I have compiled it successfully. But when I press the F5 button to start debugging ,it shows messages like below.

```
Unable to start debugging. Program path ' /home/jopillar/csapp/main'
is missing or invalid. 
GDB failed with message:
/home/jopillar/csapp/main: No such file or directory. This may occur
if the process's executable was changed after the process wasstarted,such as when installing an update.Try re-launching the application or restarting the machine.
```

But when I launch the program directly using the GDB with the command

> gdb /home/jopillar/csapp/main

It is successed.
so how can I debug the program with the vscode.

Comment: In the error message `' /home/jopillar/csapp/main'` there's some blanks before the first `/`. In your vscode config files, do you have any double-quoted strings that accidentally have blanks in them?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick tks. you pointed out the true problem. I may be asking a stupid question. lol